# Compiling (NS/Cocoa) Emacs on OSX with SVG support

Tags: emacs, development

Can anyone explain how to build Emacs `--with-ns` and SVG support on OS X?

Notes:

- `--with-rsvg` isn't working (when librsvg is installed, ie. via Homebrew)
- FYI, The [Emacs Mac port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port) uses webkit to provide SVG support, although that build adds far too many things I don't want.

I want to just compile in support for SVG on Cocoa Emacs, I'm not averse to patching, and if no answers are available, I'll see if I can patch over from the [Emacs Mac port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port)

*(Assume latest stable version of Emacs 24.2, building from source)*

#### Update:

I've tried running `brew install emacs --cocoa --svg` without success.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps this question is off topic here (see FAQ). Please post to stackoverflow.com. Thanks.

Comment: @Globalnomad - [raised on meta.](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/are-questions-about-compiling-open-source-applications-on-os-x-off-topic-here) - [also see](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/515/are-ports-related-questions-off-topic-for-ask-different/516#516)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation of the Emacs latest version (25.0.50) works fine using this command:

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --cocoa --with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick
```

Comment: Good news.  Still, now I'm hooked on Emacs Mac Port's pixel scrolling.  I'll give it a go anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that’s the only downside. On the other hand I often had the problem that pixel-wise scrolling was sluggish. Line-wise scrolling is on the other hand a little bit too sensitive, but I also got used to it pretty quickly-

Comment: I tried building, however I got `ranlib: file: libgnu.a((u64|unistd).o) has no symbols` errors.

Comment: Try `brew update`, then `brew upgrade` (might take a while) and finally the Emacs install command above. If it still does not work, try running `brew doctor` and see if there is something broken.

Comment: Tried all those already unfortunately.  Only Quartz is out of date, I will update it and try again.

Comment: installed fine on a couple of machines without any intervention (std. step of `brew update` of course) - wish I knew why that other machine's config is out of whack.

Comment: reboot fixed the errant machine... ;)

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Too busy modeling sea parks http://i.onionstatic.com/avclub/4364/15/16x9/800.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get this working, and instead went with the [Emacs Mac Port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port)

Turns out it's much better than I'd thought.